# Javascript: Waiting for one (or multiple) condition in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, wait

I want to check a condition for `k` times for a value to be true, inside a For loop, each time I want to wait 2 seconds, after that I want to go next iteration of the for a loop. For example, I tried something like below -

```
var k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function F_stTimer() {
      if (B[i].innerText === "S") {
        var A = "True"; //just for example
        if (A === true && k == 0) {
          // Do something
          k = k + 1;
          i = i - 1; // so , I can check the ith element again once start the loop again
        } //if
        else if (A === true && k > 0 && k < 5) { //checking 5 times for A to be false

          k = k + 1;

        }, i * 2000);
      i = i - 1;
    } //if
    else if (A === true && k == 5) {
      k = 0;
    } //if

  } // if 
}, 5000);
} // i loop
```

But the above type of code is not working because I do not change when it is inside `setTimeout`.

Anyway, can anyone help me with the problem I have?

One does not need to follow the way I mentioned above, what I want to do is-

**check a condition for `k` times for a value to be true, inside a For loop, each time I want wait t seconds (duration of each delay/interval of delay), after that, I want to go next iteration of the for a loop.**

Plz comment for further clarification.

Comment: `"True" !== true`!

Comment: setTimeout is not going to stop the loop from executing

Comment: @PaulJanicki yes, how can I do that? that is the problem, I want loop to be stopped until my checking is finished, can u help?

Comment: @NinaScholz not cclear, plz clarify

Comment: `A` has a value which is not checked. please add an example, what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function that takes two arguments:

1. howManyTimes - number of times you want to iterate
2. howOften - in what intervals you want to do the check (in milliseconds)

```js
function checkInIntervals(howManyTimes, howOften) {
 var counter = 0;
  
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter++;
        if (counter === howManyTimes) {
         clearInterval(interval);
        }
       // do something
        console.log(counter, 'iteration')
    }, howOften)
}

// run the function
checkInIntervals(10, 2000);
```

Inside the interval the counter is incremented and when it's equal the the desired number of iterations, the interval is cleared and the execution stops.

Comment: Why the below part does not appear in the new window, I changed your code in below way -

Comment: @Mike apparently it appears, remove the `T.document.close();` and you will see that it appears before `T.document.write('Where are you?');` is executed. SetInterval doesn't stop the code below from execution. `T.document.write('This text does not appear.');` is executed and written to the document, but it's removed by `T.document.close();`

Comment: Yes I know that, but I need to close so that the code run again previous text  does not stay there, also, even if I don;t keep close, the text appear first . not last , how can I make it appear first? plz hlp

Comment: ``function checkInIntervals(howManyTimes, howOften) { 
var T = window.open("", "MsgWindow","width=400,height=600"); var counter = 0; 
var interval = setInterval(function() {
 T.document.title = 'MIKE!'; counter++;
 if (counter === howManyTimes) { 
  clearInterval(interval); } 
// do something
T.document.write('Where are you?'); 
T.document.write("<br/>"); 
console.log(counter, 'iteration');
 }, howOften) 
T.document.write('This text does not appear.');//problem
T.document.write("<br/>");}``

^^ this is without close

Comment: @Mike if you need to run `T.document.write('This text does not appear.')` after the setInterval is done, the easiest way is to put the code inside the if statement you already have, right after `clearInterval` method is called. Then that text should appear at the end

Answer (score 1):

You could take an interval and check a counter.

```js
var counter = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        counter++;
        if (counter === 5) {
            counter = 0;
            console.log('five');
        } else {
            console.log('not five');
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: where is a condition that needs to be checked k times in each iteration?

Comment: what do you mean? why k-times? in each iteration? you could iterate faster (with a shorter interval) and check in each interval.

Comment: i have no idea. please edit your question with additional information. what you have, what should be done and what is the result after - or in between.